# Magento 2 how to setParentBlock for an existing block?

Tags: magento2, layout, blocks, magento-2.1

In Magento 1, when I want to make a block to be parent of an existing block, I only need to do this

```
$this->setParentBlock($parentBlock);
```

In Magento 1, the implementation is in `Mage_Core_Block_Abstract` class

```
/**
 * Set parent block
 *
 * @param   Mage_Core_Block_Abstract $block
 * @return  Mage_Core_Block_Abstract
 */
public function setParentBlock(Mage_Core_Block_Abstract $block)
{
    $this->_parentBlock = $block;
    return $this;
}
```

Now in Magento 2, I can only see the getParentBlock method:

```
/**
     * Retrieve parent block
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock|bool
     */
    public function getParentBlock()
    {
        $layout = $this->getLayout();
        if (!$layout) {
            return false;
        }
        $parentName = $layout->getParentName($this->getNameInLayout());
        if ($parentName) {
            return $layout->getBlock($parentName);
        }
        return false;
    }
```

My problem is when I tried to extend `Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Info` class, my class need to have  a parent block in order to work. You can see the reason in Info class

```
/**
     * Retrieve required options from parent
     *
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _beforeToHtml()
    {
        if (!$this->getParentBlock()) {
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                __('Please correct the parent block for this block.')
            );
        }
        $this->setOrder($this->getParentBlock()->getOrder());

        foreach ($this->getParentBlock()->getOrderInfoData() as $key => $value) {
            $this->setDataUsingMethod($key, $value);
        }

        parent::_beforeToHtml();
    }
```

I always got the error "Please correct the parent block for this block."

Comment: Did you solve this somehow?

Answer (score 3):

In Magento 2, the `setParentBlock` method is deprecated.

To assign a parent block you need to do the following:

```
$this->_view->getLayout()->setChild($parentName, $childName, $childAlias);
```

Where `$this->_view` is `\Magento\Framework\App\ViewInterface`

Alternatively you can also do:

```
$this->layout->setChild($parentName, $childName, $childAlias);
```

Where `$this->layout` is `\Magento\Framework\View\LayoutInterface`

NB: This `setChild` method is different than the `setChild` method from `Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock`

Comment: Hi @Raphael, thanks for your answer, but it doesn't solve my problem. The setChild function in Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock called the setChild function in \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutInterface. And even before that, the addChild function of Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock call setChild of itself. I used addChild already and what I've got is "Element with ID ...is already defined" (the exception in renameElement of Structure class). Still try to find out why